# Can't find my files in users after moving

Tags: file-recovery

This morning, when I turned on my laptop, I realised that all my files and folders were missing. Luckily I was able to locate them at users. I moved the personal folders to the already pinned ones to locate them easily. I restarted everything just in case. When it turned back on, all my files and folders were missing again even at users but everything else, including the wallpaper and some apps had been restored. I have a very important assignment to submit but that one is gone(was at documents) is there a way to restore restore everything?

Comment: In most cases a pinned location is just a link and not a real location. Determine the real location for your files and keep them there. Also know what One Drive is doing if you use that.

Comment: Open windows explorer in C:, and search for the missing file(s) as described  here: http://hs.windows.microsoft.com/hhweb/content/m-en-us/p-6.2/id-8d6963c6-f737-4009-a061-22cbb976bdc3/

Comment: It sounds like you’re being given a temporary profile, hence the reason, you believe the document to be gone. Can you confirm the user profile directory in your normal user profile and not a temporary one?

Comment: ... and irrespective of find them now you should have backup of anything you can't afford to loose.

Comment: @1NN, thanks but everytime I click on what I've searched for,  it says the file is unavailable or located or moved

Comment: @Ramhound, I have but both the temporary one and the normal user one are empty

Comment: @ChanganAuto thanks, I've learnt my lesson. My onedrive was full so I lost my recent documents.

Comment: If Onedrive deleted the files, you sould find them in the onedrive recycle bin, check here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/restore-deleted-files-or-folders-in-onedrive-949ada80-0026-4db3-a953-c99083e6a84f  Also, check your windows thrash bin

Comment: @VictoriaDarko - That’s relevant information which you didn’t include in your question

Comment: @1NN thank you, I'll do so

Comment: @Ramhound really sorry about that

Comment: @VictoriaDarko you should edit your question to make it better, adding the information that we've helped you discover down here in the comments, to the question itself.